# how to check every element in an array when checking for nicknames

Tags: python

So basically im writing a program on python and one of the sub-routines i need is no repeat nicknames, so what i did is added all the nicknames into a txt file then i want to read the file and make sure the nickname isn't the same as the nicknames in the file. Here's the code :

```
sAskNick = input ("What nickname would you like to proceed with?: ")

nicknames = open("nicknames.txt","a+")
aAllNicks = []

with open ("nicknames.txt") as f:
aAllNicks = f.read().splitlines()

for i in range(0,4):
    while sAskNick == aAllNicks[i]:
        print("Nickname used/inappropriate")

    else:
        print("Valid nickname")
        break
```

In this the nicknames.txt just contains a list of nicknames in each line, 5 nicknames are in the file.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something when the given nickname is in that file:

```
given_nickname = input('What is your nickname?')

#Read the file:
nicknames = open(r'c:\filelocation','r').read().splitlines()

for element in range(len(nicknames)):
    if given_nickname in nicknames:
        print('{0} is in the nicknames list'.format(given_nickname))
    else:
        print('{0} is NOT in the list'.format(given_nickname))
```

If you want to edit the text file everytime you enter some nickname, you can use the following to do that.
**NOTE:**
Of course, this case going to work if you keep the each nickname in each line with a clean text file:

```
#Read the file:
file_location = r'somepath'
read_file = open(file_location,'r').read().splitlines()
nicknames = list(read_file) #catch the file as a list, its an optional line for cleaner code

def edit_file(nickname,file_location):
    f = open(file_location,'a').write('\n{0}'.format(nickname)) # before adding each nickname,start a new line in the text file



while True:
    given_nickname = input('What is your nickname?')
    if given_nickname not in nicknames:
        print('Welcome {0}!'.format(given_nickname))
        edit_file(nickname = given_nickname,file_location = file_location)
        break # stop the execution

    else:
        print('Error! {0} already chosen!'.format(given_nickname))
        #looping over the while loop if nickname is taken
```

There are plenty of goals that you can achieve on this question. I believe one of these two could get it done.